# Is the visual studio release mode exe file standalone or not?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I want to build a single standalone executable file for a windows console application built in Visual Studio 2019. By standalone, I mean that I want a single exe file that I can move to any location on any computer and it will still run without extra files surrounding it (no dependencies).

For the life of me, I can't find a clear answer anywhere.

**Question 1**: Is the visual studio "release" executable file standalone?
**Question 2**: How do I make a standalone exe file that will run anywhere, no matter what libraries my code depends on?
**Question 3**: Can this be done inside visual studio, or do I need other software to do it?

Comment: Set the project options to statically link all the libraries (including the Runtime Support).  Also you will need to target the earliest release of MS-Windows that you want to support.

Comment: Release mode if not built statically requires the visual studio redistributable to be installed. The downloads for that are here: [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) Since VS2015 to VS2019 are binary compatible there is a single download for all 3 versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Debug applications are not permitted to be installed on machines that don't have Visual Studio installed so the debug runtime is not present in the download. There is an exception to this rule for testing but you must supply the dlls alongside your executable.

Comment: You can package your executable in an installer package that contains the redistributable. I package my executables with NSIS (generated from CMake) for my Qt projects I develop on Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-deploying-a-visual-cpp-application-by-using-a-setup-project?view=vs-2019) to deploy a Visual C++ Application.

For third-party libraries, you could select static linking version. If there is no static link version and only dll, copy the corresponding dll together when publishing.

For the c++ runtime library, select the static compilation method: `Properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library->Multi-threaded (/MT)`.

Also, you could use `depends.exe` (a Microsoft small tool) to view the dll, and then package it together.